# How to limit the number of columns of the table created from PHP while loop

Tags: php, html

I have this table created from php while loop from MySQL. The problem is the column goes outside the page. Using CSS `word-wrap` did not work.

[image]

**Here's what I am looking for**

[image]

The original code. Sorry for the ugly code.

```
<?php
// 1
$sqlCount = "SELECT MAX(rowascol_id) AS totalcount FROM rowascol";
$resultCount = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCount);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCount);
    $totalCount = $row['totalcount'];

// 2
$sqlRowAsCol = "SELECT * FROM rowascol";
$resultRowAsCol = mysqli_query($con, $sqlRowAsCol);
?>

<table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="6" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;">
    <thead style='background-color: #cee8ff;'>
        <?php 
        for($i = 1; $i <= $totalCount; $i++){
            echo "<th>$i</th>";
        }?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultRowAsCol)) {
            $data['col1'][] = $row['n1'];
            $data['col2'][] = $row['n2'];
            $data['col3'][] = $row['n3'];
            $data['col4'][] = $row['n4'];
            $data['col5'][] = $row['n5'];
            $data['col6'][] = $row['n6'];
            $data['ans'][] = $row['ans'];
            $data['edit'][] = $row['rowascol_id'];
        }?>

        <!-- looping the table -->
        <?php
        // 1
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['col1'] as $col1) {
                echo "<td>$col1</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['col2'] as $col2) {
                echo "<td>$col2</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['col3'] as $col3) {
                echo "<td>$col3</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['col4'] as $col4) {
                echo "<td>$col4</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['col5'] as $col5) {
                echo "<td>$col5</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['col6'] as $col6) {
                echo "<td>$col6</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr  id='ansCell' style='font-weight: bold;'>";
            foreach ($data['ans'] as $ans) {
                echo "<td>$ans</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($data['edit'] as $edit) {
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<a href='edit.php?id=".$edit."'>Edit</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
         ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't break `<table>` element. Render it as bunch of `ul > li` to have power of breaking them as needed

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not possible to make a responsive layout using the "table" element.

If your cells have allways the same size you can try something like this:

- create each column as a "div" style="diaplay:inline-block;"
- include your columns inside (as tables or just as "divs")

Example:

```css
.tablecol{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid #555555;
  margin:2px 0;
}
.tablecol td{
  border:1px solid #333333;
  width:30px;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H1</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H2</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H3</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H4</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H5</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H6</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H7</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H8</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H9</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H10</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H12</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H13</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H14</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H15</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H16</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H17</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H18</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H19</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="tablecol">
 <table>
  <tr><th>H20</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Your PHP Loop should look something like this:

```
 echo '<div class="tablecol"><table>';
        foreach ($data['col2'] as $col2) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$col2.'</td></tr>';
        }
    echo '</table></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks! @federico I guess yours is the closest of what I want. Lots of repetitive HTML code. I guess there is no other way as of now I think. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

A table can't break. A solution is to create each vertical row as a div (with float: left or display: inline-block). This way each vertical row will be placed to the right of the previous, and if there is no more room, it will automatically jump to the next line. E.g.

```
<div style="float:left;">
   <p>Column</p>
   <p>Column</p>
   <p>Column</p>
   <p>etc...</p>
</div>
```

You can optionally wrap all the rows in a div to control their collected width.

Comment: If there are no other options, I guess i have to go with yours. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just thinking why don't you make it in horizontal way for a better viewing experience...

*not sure is correct or not due to the sql queries.... try to modified...idea is something like this:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="6" style="text-align: center;">

<tbody>
    <?php 
    for($j = 0; $j <= $totalCount; $j++){ 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$j</td>"; // your title

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultRowAsCol);
            $edit =$row['rowascol_id'];

            echo "<td>".$row['n1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['n2']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['n3']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['n4']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['n5']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['n6']."</td>";                
            echo "<td>". $row['ans']."</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='edit.php?id=".$edit."'>Edit</a></td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }?>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: It has to be in a given way. I cannot change to this.

Comment: edited... but you might try to understand a bit on the code.... sorry if my code is wrong... but the idea is something like that

Comment: Actually you did not provide the code, its a table with numbers. Anyway, i do appreciate your suggestion. I do understand my code, I guess my previous cooment looked different to the readers. What i meant was the structure remains the same it has to be in horizontal order and only the columns can be displayed in vertical. Does that make sense